# How to price a derivative security in a trinomial asset pricing model

Tags: option-pricing, arbitrage, binomial, trinomial-tree

I am reading the first two chapters of Shreve's book "Stochastic Calculus for finance 1". The author discusses the question of how to price a derivative security assuming a binomial asset pricing model and then derives the delta hedging formula:
$$\Delta_i(w)=\frac{X_{i+1}(wH)-X_{i+1}(wT)}{S_{i+1}(wH)-S_{i+1}(wT)}$$
How sensitive are the author's findings to the assumption of a binomial asset pricing model $\{H,T\}^n$. What if our sample space is changed to $\{a,b,c\}^n$ (i.e. a trinomial asset pricing model), then the quantities $\frac{X_{i+1}(wb)-X_{i+1}(wa)}{S_{i+1}(wb)-S_{i+1}(wa)}$, $\frac{X_{i+1}(wc)-X_{i+1}(wa)}{S_{i+1}(wc)-S_{i+1}(wa)}$ need not be equal and so the author's discussion of how to price a derivative security does not generalize from the binomial model to the trinomial model . Furthermore, in the trinomial model there does not seem to be a unique risk neutral probability measure (unlike the binomial model which has a unique risk neutral probability measure). How does one price a derivative security in a trinomial model ?